# Formato de número teléfonico de 9 dígitos - Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

Estoy intentado hacer el formato de un número de 9 dígitos, Ejm: `999 999 999`, cada vez que se escucha el evento `keyup`, cada 3 números debe agregarse un espacio, esto lo hago correctamente. Ahora cuando presiono la letra de Retroceso o Backspace me vuelve a generar un espacio, tengo que mantener presionada la tecla para limpiar el input, esto lo pude resolver usando el método `trim()` en el 2do replace.

Al hacer esto me da otro problema, y es que ya no me genera automáticamente el espacio cada 3 carácteres sino en el 4to. Ejm al usar trim: presionas 123, si lo dejas tal y como está seguirá asi, al presionar otra tecla recién agrega el espacio, en cambio al quitar trim, cuando se presiona el 3 automáticamente se genera un espacio.

Entonces cómo podría generar un espacio cada 3 números y borrar el espacio agregado cuando cada fila de 3 números esté vacía? Muchas gracias de antemano, espero se haya podido entender mi pregunta.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  
  e.target.value = value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 ');

})
```

```html
<input id="input" maxlength="11" />
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Y si generas el espacio cuando tecleas el siguiente grupo de 3 dígitos? D esta manera el último espacio no se agrega. Simplmente añades un replace

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  
  e.target.value = value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 ').replace(/\s$/,'');

})
```

```html
<input id="input" maxlength="11" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías usar input type="tel" podrías aprovechar el autocompletado de cada usuario y seria más correcto.